# Disadvantage to very long Texture2D objects in XNA?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I am using a Texture2D object as a tilesheet. It's one-dimensional- one tile tall and however many tiles long.

I'm just curious if there's any disadvantage (Aside from being more difficult to edit, I guess) to having them laid out like this as opposed to a more compact way, e.g. instead of 64x1 tiles, make it 16x16. It wouldn't be very hard to change it, but I figure why bother if there's no hurt in having a long image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real disadvantage is that you'll hit the maximum width (2048 on the `Reach` profile, 4096 on `HiDef`) of the texture with fewer sprites.

This isn't really a problem because, when it happens, it's so trivial to add support for more rows.

---

Seeing as you've asked the question, there is *one* obscure, performance-related thing that is at least interesting to be aware of, even though you *almost never* need to worry about it.

A texture's pixel data is stored in CPU memory in a row-by-row order. So if your tiles are stored horizontally, you try and read or write the pixels for a single tile (ie: `GetData` and `SetData`), you will be accessing many small, spread-out sections of memory. If you stored your tiles vertically, then each tile would occupy a single large section of memory - this has better cache coherency and can be copied with fewer operations (ie: it's faster).

This is **not** a problem on the GPU, where textures are stored with a layout such that all nearby pixels (not just the ones to the left and right) are stored nearby in memory.

Comment: I can't for the life of me imagine how the GPU could do that. Do you have a reference for the last paragraph?

Comment: GPUs lay out their textures using a technique called swizzling (not to be confused with vector swizzling) that interleaves the row and column data.

Answer (score 1):

Having a long image can make it easier to 'index' sprites in the sheet. For example, in your case, the image at index `i` is located at coordinates `(w * i, 0)`, where `w` is the width of one sprite. Having it in a square would mean that you need more complex math to find the right sprite. It would be at `(w * (i % 16), h * (i / 16))`. (By the way, those coordinates are in pixels.)

So use the long image! It'll keep your code cleaner.

Comment: That's not the math I'm worried about honestly. sure, it looks a bit cleaner from not having to do the extra moddiv, but aside from that they're basically the same.

I'm more curious whether there's any sort of issue when it comes to how XNA handles the texture at a low level. Say I had 100 16*16 tiles: Would a 16*1600 texture be worse than a 160*160?

Comment: I can't think of anything that would cause a problem with long rows. There may be small performance improvements either way, but they probably wouldn't be measurable.